# templated silverlight button not resizing correctly

Tags: silverlight, xaml, button, controltemplate

I would like to create a UI similar to Visual Studio-s open documents stripe. The main idea is, that I have a listbox, which I fill with the open documents' thumbnails. I have the following Templates applied:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="23" d:DesignWidth="100">
        <Rectangle x:Name="background" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
            Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource LinearMain02}" Margin="0"/>
      <TextBlock Text="text" Margin="4,0,25,0" Foreground="{StaticResource SolidBaseBrush}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource SolidStrongBrush}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
            Margin="0,0,4,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Width="15" Height="15" BorderThickness="0" Opacity="0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>


<Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Height}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
            <Ellipse Stroke="{StaticResource SolidBaseBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The ListBox itself is not much to look at, but here it is:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="list_tabs"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Thumbnails}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThumbnail, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabListItemTemplate}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
    Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" 
    Background="{StaticResource LinearStrong10}">
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemHeight="30"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

It seems like it doesn't matter how long the content of the item is, it remains 100px wide. That I want to change, so the item would follow the width of its contents. What did I forget to set?

Comment: According to the info so far provided the item contents should limit themselves to the width of the listbox (possible - the width of the scrollviewer vertical bar).  Is this not what you are seeing? Can you show more of the Xaml like the ListBox itself an its container?